# Extremely slow JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join

We're trying to join tables using this query, however, it is extremely slow to the extend which is not possible to apply to production.

Appreciate if we could get assistance at improving the query.

```
SELECT  
    U.user_id, U.user_verify
    , IFNULL(C.value,'Unspecified') AS Country
    , IFNULL(S.value,'Unspecified') AS State 
    , IFNULL(CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(U.user_city,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(U.user_city,2))),'Unspecified') AS city
    , IFNULL(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(U.user_dob),0) AS AGE
    , IFNULL(G.value,'Unspecified') AS Gender
    , IFNULL(A.name,'') AS `app_name`
    , U.user_verify_date
    , IFNULL(U._rec_created_on,NULL) AS registration_date
    , IFNULL(LS._rec_created_on,NULL) AS log_date
        
FROM userext AS U   
    LEFT JOIN profile_country AS C ON (U.user_nationality=C.id AND C.kwd_lang='en' AND C._rec_status='SHOW')
    LEFT JOIN profile_state AS S ON (U.user_state=S.id AND S.kwd_lang='en' AND S._rec_status='SHOW')
    LEFT JOIN profile_gender AS G ON (U.user_gender=G.id AND G.kwd_lang='en' AND G._rec_status='SHOW')
    
    LEFT JOIN logservice AS LS ON LS.user_id=CAST(U.user_id AS CHAR)
    LEFT JOIN app AS A ON (UPPER(LS.log_id_2)=UPPER(A.client_id) AND A.lang='en')
    
WHERE U._rec_status='SHOW'
    AND LS.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need the structures of your tables (as text - you can also put them on dbfiddle.uk) and the output of explain analyze (mysql > 8). Please always include  your version of mysql!

Answer (score 1):

If you *join* by a column, then BOTH "left" and "right" columns should be indexed.

If you *filter* by a column, then that column should [probably] be indexed.

Your joins with multiple conditions might benefit from composite indexes on all three fields (e.g. profile_country's id, kwd_lang and _rec_status).

A `Left [Outer] Join` combined with an `is not null` condition on the "right" table (your `logservice LS`, in this case) effectively reduces the condition to an `Inner Join`.  OK, this won't impact query *performance*, but will make the *intent* of your query much clearer to readers, including *you*, after a month or two of working on anything else!

Answer (score 1):

This does not make sense to me:

```
   LEFT JOIN  profile_state AS S  ON (U.user_state=S.id
              AND  S.kwd_lang='en'
              AND  S._rec_status='SHOW' )
```

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `S`, then `U.user_state=S.id` this i all that is needed to locate the one row.  The other tests might exclude that row from being shown.  But, since it is a `LEFT` Join, it will still be shown, but as `NULL`.  (If `id` is not the PK, I will take another look at it.)

This also seems strange:

```
LEFT JOIN  logservice AS LS  ON LS.user_id=CAST(U.user_id AS CHAR)
...
WHERE  LS.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

That is equivalent to

```
INNER JOIN  logservice AS LS  ON LS.user_id=CAST(U.user_id AS CHAR)
```

(without the test in the `WHERE`)

Why `CAST(U.user_id AS CHAR)`?  Is `user_id` not `VARCHAR`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

This is a significant performance problem, and is easily solved:

```
ON (UPPER(LS.log_id_2)=UPPER(A.client_id)
```

Simply make the two columns have the same `CHARACTER SET` and the same `COLLATION`, and make the `COLLATION` "Case Insensitive" -- that is, use a name ending in `_ci`.  Then, this is much faster because of being "sargable":

```
ON LS.log_id_2 = A.client_id
```

Some of these INDEXes may help:

```
U:  INDEX(_rec_status, user_nationality)
C:  INDEX(kwd_lang, _rec_status, id, value)
S:  INDEX(kwd_lang, _rec_status, id, value)
G:  INDEX(kwd_lang, _rec_status, id, value)
A:  INDEX(client_id,  name, lang)
LS:  INDEX(user_id,  _rec_created_on, log_id_2)
```